# Is it okay to have plaintext database username and password inside Dataset.xsd file in a C# winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms, security, dataset, connection-string

I have a **dataset.xsd** file within a C# winform application. when I opened the **datased.xsd** file with notepad++ I found all the database authentication information **(id, password)**. 
I read about encrypting  connectionstrings in the configuration file and using the "aspnet_regiis" command and I applied it on my project but the content of the **dataset.xsd** still readable.

Is my project secure? do I need further steps to make it more secure? 
if note, what should I do next?

**Content of the app.config file:**
[image]

**Content of the dataSet.xsd:** 
[image]

**Is it possible to set the encrypted ConnectionString from app.config to the dataset.xsd file???**
I appreciate your time in helping me to answer this question.

Comment: this link mybe help you : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10136/Encrypt-and-decrypt-DataSets-to-XML-files

Comment: XSD file is a schema.It doesn't contain values. Any login page requires a id and password so that is not secure.It may be considered secure if the format of the id and password are in the xsd.For example if you require an email for ID.Is first initial and last name instead of firstname dot lastname considered secure?Encryption security is determined by the amount of time it takes to break the encryption.  If it will take 100 years to decrypt the data then it is considered secure.  If it take only 50 years it is less secure.  Do putting in the xsd the id format it less secure, but still secure.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, I am adding more details for my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Dears, I found the solution by removing the second connection tag in the dataSet.xsd file, the first connection tag in the file is the encrypted one and it is enough to make the code work, so the second tag only causes security vulnerability and the code will work like a charm without this tag.

**The code after modification:**
[image]